# How do I replace two lines each other in editor in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, git

I have this:

```
pick 887b66f add 222 Dziewiecsil to flowers new title
pick dc331cb new name of beginning commit
```

And I want to get this:

```
pick dc331cb new name of beginning commit
pick 887b66f add 222 Dziewiecsil to flowers new title
```

Is there a way to do this in quick way using keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has some examples of how to swap two adjacent lines in the editor vi:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines

From the link above:

To swap the current line with the one below, tap {esc} and type:

```
ddp
```

To swap the current line with the one above, tap {esc} and type:

```
ddkP
```